# Why would my Raspberry Pi only display a blinking "_" after bootup

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

I've attached a HDMI monitor to my Pi running Raspbian. In the past external displays have worked fine.

Recently, when I connect my Pi to a HDMI monitor I get the usual bootup screens and the bootup log scroll. I can even access NOOBS and configure it there. But as soon as the bootup scroll finishes, I'm stuck at a screen with a blinking "_" in the corner. The Pi is otherwise working fine, since I can log in via SSH.

The only hardware change I have made is to add a 4D systems 2.5inch GPIO touchscreen. I can't remember if the HDMI output worked after installing the GPIO display.

Comment: With a keyboad attached, try cycling through Ctrl-Alt-F[1-6] and see if anything changes.

Comment: Yeah, that got me to the terminal. I'll go back to trying to work out how to get a GUI running on external monitors. The GUI works fine on the GPIO, so I shouldn't have too much trouble.

Comment: Those keys take you to an array of [virtual terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) represented by `/dev/tty[1-6]`.  Normally at boot you start on tty1, but if you are running a GUI, that will occupy one of them and if it is not the first one, the system will switch to the one with X running on it.  If that's not there, it could be the one with the blinking cursor (something is hanging on a mishap), in which case you may or may not be able to start a second instance.